# How to get element height without DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, handlebars.js, mustache

I am building a SSR angular app and I got some logic which handles the location of different templates but in order to complete the logic I need the element height of each template without using the DOM.

**The project, in short**

I am building an app that styles HTML into looking like a PDF and then using that HTML to create a PDF using Aspose.

**Why SSR?**

SSR is needed for other platforms than a browser to get the HTML that then renders into a PDF. I.e, I have an Api that is able to call the SSR app, get the full HTML and print it into a PDF.

**Why Angular?**

The entire project is build on Angular and I need to be able to reuse the component that renders the PDF-look-alike HTML for direct editing within the HTML.

**Now that you are up to speed, back to the problem at hand**

The HTML consists of multiple templates which height changes according to the data added. In order to push sections down (or up) to a corresponding page I need the height of each template (after data is added) to know if the content exceeds the page height.

When navigating to the SSR app via a browser everything is rendered fine because I am able to make use of the DOM and query into each template to get the height of the element. But when accessing the app via an Api or Postman I get the HTML back but the logic that handles the section placements are broken because it doens't have the height - **SO** I need to get/calculate the height of each template **WITHOUT** the use of the DOM.

**What I have found so far**

I am pretty new at SSR but everything that manipulates the DOM or something that only a browser engine has doesn't seem to be a viable way - so `@ViewChild`, `ngAfterViewInit`, `setTimeout` and other DOM Api's or functionalities cannot be used in this case. I need to be able to prerender each template at the lifecycle step NgOnInit (at the latest).

Using libraries like **[Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)** or **[HandleBars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)** renders the HTML fine from the data that I give it but I **ONLY** get the Html - no dimensions at all.

I have also tried to use `createElement('div')` after Mustache or HandleBars creates the element and add it into the newly created `div`. This adds the element fine to the `div`'s `childnodes` but it doesn't calculate the height.

Maybe I am missing something using one of these libraries?

**Is it even possible?**

So far I am getting the impression that it is not possible to get an element dimensions from code without entering the DOM?

**Headless Chrome?**

Is running a Headless Chrome the only way to create a sort-of virtual DOM that I can manipulate from code?

Sorry for all the text and minimal amount of code but this question is more on how my approach should be and if I am heading in the wrong direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to go with Headless Chrome - at least in my situation.
Without a DOM you are not able to render the height and if you do not have a browser engine to render this for you, you'll need to spin up an engine that can - i.e Headless Chrome.

Using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) was the easiest way for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you describe is that the actual height of the DOM element is calculable only after that the element is inserted in the DOM.

For example, if you compile your Handlebars template and you insert in a new `div` element created with  `createElement('div')`, the actual height will still be 0. 
You will need to append your `div` to a current existing DOM element in order to calculate its height.

A workaround i often use is to load the component you want to know its height into the bottom of the page (or in a location the user is not currently watching), calculate its height and then eliminate it.

All the process is almost instantaneous and allows you to get the actual height of the element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Greedo but I do not have a 'current existing DOM element' to do what you suggest. Anywho - we went with headless chrome and that works perfectly. :)